# Lag when visible frame layout that has been put beside another resizing frame layout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have 2 Frame Layout in Relative Layout like that :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav_bar" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/for_dashboard_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/for_main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Case 1 : I set the **for_main_layout** adjust resize when the **for_dashboard_layout** is visible, so it has been lag / delay about 2-3 seconds

Case 2 : The **for_dashboard_layout** being **GONE** and the **for_main_layout** being resize, next I show the **for_dashboard_layout** by call **VISIBLE**, same problem ( lag about 2-3 seconds ) has been happend

Any body can help me to solve that...

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell until it's clear what else is happening around your logic to show and hide your dashboard, maybe your dashboard is trying to load large data or a list with many elements. Try replacing with INVISIBLE instead of GONE to reduce the time lag.

Comment: if replace GONE to INVISIBLE, it changes to case 1, the root cause maybe happen when visible a layout when another being resize, but I have no idea to solve that.

Comment: You will have to post your java code. I'm not sure if I know the problem with the information you have provided